# PhoneGap with Android 4.0 ignores meta-viewport

Tags: android, cordova, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Does anyone know a work around with PhoneGap 1.2 that allows you deal with the new Android OS 4.0 devices where it ignores the viewport?

I've seen where you can add the following code, but it hasn't worked for me. Am I missing something here? How can I get 4.0 with PhoneGap 1.2 to recognize the viewport? The viewport works fine in Mobile Web.

```
public class PhoneGapExample extends DroidGap
{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
     this.appView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
     this.appView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit your DroidGap.java or download an updated version of the Phonegap/Callback framework.

Around line 200 in DroidGap.java you'll see the setup of the webview, change the following lines:

```
// Old: this.appView.setInitialScale(100);
this.appView.setInitialScale(0);
```

The viewport-argument ignores width and user-scalable altogether when using device-width and no as values, I guess they want us to use the android-specific values:

```
E/Web Console( 4739): Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" not recognized
E/Web Console( 4739): Viewport argument value "no;" for key "user-scalable" not recognized.
```

Comment: I've been told that has been fixed in version 1.3.0

Comment: That's correct, in phonegap 1.3.0 they use 0 as initial scale, so same solution.